# Entity Framework 6 Mapping Composite Keys Across Classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following classes;

```
public partial class DriverType : Entity<int>
{
    [Column("Id")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "drivertypeid")]
    public override int ID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "drivertype")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public partial class Driver : AuditableEntity<int>
    {
        [Key,Column("driverId", Order=0)]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="driverid")]
        public override int ID { get; set; }

        [Key,Column("type", Order=1)]
        [ForeignKey("DriverType")]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName="drivertypeid")]
        public int DriverTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual DriverType DriverType { get; set; }

        ..... reduced for brevity

    }

public partial class DriversToVehicle
    {
        [Column("id"), Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

    [Column("driverId", Order = 0), ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }

    [Column("type", Order = 1), ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int DriverTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriverTypeId")]
    public virtual DriverType DriverType { get; set; }

    [Column("vehicleid")]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleID")]
    public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

and also

```
 public partial class Appointment : AuditableEntity<int>
    {
        [Column("AppointmentId")]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "appointmentid")]
        public override int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Column("driverId", Order=0),ForeignKey("Driver")]
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "driverid")]
    public int? DriverID { get; set; }

    [Column("type", Order = 1), ForeignKey("Driver")]
    public int? DriverTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriverTypeId")]
    public virtual DriverType DriverType { get; set; }

    public virtual Driver Driver { get; set; }
```

Again the above code is reduced for the question. The issue I am having is now when I try to run a migration I get the following Up() method.

```
  DropForeignKey("dbo.Appointment", "DriverID", "dbo.Driver");
                DropForeignKey("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers", "Driver_ID", "dbo.Driver");
                DropForeignKey("dbo.Driver", "Vehicle_ID", "dbo.Vehicles");
                DropForeignKey("dbo.DriversToVehicles", "driverid", "dbo.Driver");
                DropIndex("dbo.Appointment", new[] { "DriverID" });
                DropIndex("dbo.Driver", new[] { "Vehicle_ID" });
                DropIndex("dbo.DriversToVehicles", new[] { "driverid" });
                DropIndex("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers", new[] { "Driver_ID" });
                DropColumn("dbo.Driver", "driverId");
                DropColumn("dbo.Driver", "driverId");
                RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Driver", name: "id", newName: "driverId");
                RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Driver", name: "Vehicle_ID", newName: "driverId");
                DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Driver");
                DropPrimaryKey("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers");
                CreateTable(
                    "dbo.DriverTypes",
                    c => new
                        {
                            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                            Name = c.String(),
                            IsArchived = c.Boolean(),
                        })
                    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

                AddColumn("dbo.Appointment", "type", c => c.Int());
                AddColumn("dbo.DriversToVehicles", "type", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
                AddColumn("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers", "Driver_DriverTypeId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
                AlterColumn("dbo.Driver", "driverId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
                AlterColumn("dbo.Driver", "driverId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
                AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Driver", new[] { "driverId", "type" });
                AddPrimaryKey("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers", new[] { "InsurancePolicy_ID", "Driver_ID", "Driver_DriverTypeId" });
                CreateIndex("dbo.Appointment", new[] { "driverId", "type" });
                CreateIndex("dbo.Driver", "driverId");
                CreateIndex("dbo.Driver", "type");
                CreateIndex("dbo.DriversToVehicles", new[] { "driverId", "type" });
                CreateIndex("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers", new[] { "Driver_ID", "Driver_DriverTypeId" });
                AddForeignKey("dbo.Driver", "type", "dbo.DriverTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
                AddForeignKey("dbo.Appointment", "type", "dbo.DriverTypes", "Id");
                AddForeignKey("dbo.DriversToVehicles", "type", "dbo.DriverTypes", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
                AddForeignKey("dbo.Appointment", new[] { "driverId", "type" }, "dbo.Driver", new[] { "driverId", "type" });
                AddForeignKey("dbo.InsurancePolicyDrivers", new[] { "Driver_ID", "Driver_DriverTypeId" }, "dbo.Driver", new[] { "driverId", "type" });
                AddForeignKey("dbo.Driver", "driverId", "dbo.Vehicles", "id", cascadeDelete: true);
                AddForeignKey("dbo.DriversToVehicles", new[] { "driverId", "type" }, "dbo.Driver", new[] { "driverId", "type" }, cascadeDelete: true);
```

As you can see its trying to recreate duplicte columns of the same name? I assume this is due to the foreign keys its trying to set up here?

Comment: Perhaps you omitted too much code. Where is the `Vehicle` class? What changes did you mean to make? The `Vehicle_ID` (mark the underscore) is a foreign key that EF created in the database for you, but was not specified in your model. So perhaps you have a relation between `Vehicle` and `Driver` that we need to know about. Perhaps better to rethink your question and reduce it to the bare minimum code to reproduce the issue. Chances are that you will solve it yourself then.

Comment: @Dabblernl yes you are correct there was an errant public virtual List<Driver> {get;set;} left in the Vehicle class. Removing this solved the issue. Ok, so I understand going forward, How would I add a List of an object containing a composite key? is this possible only through a link class/table?

Comment: You can do this, but you need to create the two foreign keys in the child object and configure them appropriately,

Comment: Always look carefully for foreign key columns with underscores in your database. They are a pointer to the fact that EF has interpreted your configuration differently from how you intended it.